# issues using stringstream to handle binary file

Tags: c++, binary, fstream, stringstream

I'm working with a binary file that I need to grab its useful contents from. The structure is:

Comment: Doesn't feel like `stringstream` is very well suited to deal with binary files.

Comment: Not in the slightest, in fact.

Comment: The problem isn't `stringstream` (although I don't see any real use for it here); the problem is that he's trying to use formatted IO on binary data.  There's no way that will work, since the formatting is all text oriented.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual input looks like.  What's binary, and what is text?  And if most of the file is binary, null is 0, which is a valid binary value.

Comment: @JamesKanze agreed. without a *much* better definition of the input file format this is somewhat nebulous in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick look at the file, you don't have an "unknown amt of nulls" anywhere. The format appears to be:

```
N Bytes: number of animals, integer as text delimited by '\n'
24 Bytes per animal:
    16 Bytes: name of animal padded with 0
    4 Bytes: some 32 bit number (little endian)
    4 Bytes: another 32 bit number (little endian)
```

You shouldn't be reading this as a text file, but instead as a raw binary file. There's absolutely no need for a stringstream, you can simply parse the number of animals by reading in one byte at a time and adding to the previous value * 10 until you reach '\n'.